# Get the raw data of a JSON number using NSJSONSerializer

Tags: json, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to parse a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
{"amount": -9.45}
```

Using `JSONSerializer`, the amount gets parsed as a floating point number leading to errors in the numbers. This is the code I currently have:

```
import Foundation

let jsonData = "{\"amount\": -9.45}".data(using: .utf8)!
let jsonObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String: Any]
jsonObject["amount"] // -9.449999999999999
```

Is there a way I can get to the underlying string that is being parsed into a floating point number so I can parse it myself?

Notes:

- This is financial data so I'd like to parse it as either an Int or Decimal.
- I cannot control the source of the data.
- I'm trying to avoid pre-processing the data/writing my own JSON parser.

**EDIT:** After reviewing the code of the [Swift version of `JSONSerialization`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSJSONSerialization.swift) provided by Apple as part of the open source Foundation project, I do not believe that it's possible to solve this problem using the stock class. I [made a patched version of the class](https://gist.github.com/hashemi/23c6cee44585543cb6b622d7d2a99100) that parses all numbers as `Decimal`'s instead of `Int`'s or `Double`'s and that solved my problem.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "get to the underlying string that is being parsed into a float point number so I can parse it myself?" I'm not sure what you need to parse yourself. If you want the decimal value to be `-9.45` instead of `-9.449999999999999`, cast it as a Float: `jsonObject["amount"] as! Float`

Comment: @Stephen casting to Float doesn't solve the problem, just reduces the accuracy and happens to work in this particular example. For example, if the amount was `-100000.12` then `Float` would read it as `-100000.1`